# How can the absence of `@OrderColumn` generate duplicate data when reading from database?

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I have `Spring Data Jpa` application with `PostgreSQL` database. I have a fairly simple scenario: save an entity, including entities that have an `@OneToMany` relationship with it. That is, I do `messageRepository.save(entity)` (where `save` from `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository`) and thus save both `MessageEntity` and list of `DocumentEntity`.

I noticed a strange thing: if I remove the `@OrderColumn(name = "number")`, then when executing `notificationJobParameterEntityRepository.findById(jobParametersId)` (where `findById` from `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository`) I get a number of documents in `MessageEntity` that does not correspond to reality, while exactly duplicates of the same entity. Example: I save a message with list of 1 `document` (really 1 `document` is saved to the table), but when calling `notificationJobParameterEntityRepository.findById(jobParametersId)` I see the list of 4 `documents`, they are all the same (the same `id`, the same other fields), i.e. they are all duplicates.

Why is this happening? Why do I get duplicates when reading data without `@OrderColumn(name = "number")`?

[image]

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "_message")
data class MessageEntity(
    val text: String,

    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "message_id")
    // the same @OrderColumn without which duplicates appear when reading NotificationJobParametersEntity
    @OrderColumn(name = "number")
    val documents: List<DocumentEntity> = emptyList(),
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: UUID? = null
}
```

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "_document")
data class DocumentEntity(
    val number: Long,

    val storageId: String,
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: UUID? = null
    @CreatedDate
    lateinit var createdAt: Instant
}
```

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "_notification_job_parameters")
data class NotificationJobParametersEntity(
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "message_id")
    val message: MessageEntity,
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: UUID? = null
}
```